# Accessing passed argument variable and passing it as map key

Tags: javascript

I am working on some project in js lately and I came acreoss a situation where my code can be reduced  roughly upto 50% if I could access passed argument to one of function and use them as key. I am new to js, hence little explanation would help a lot.

What I am looking for

```
Foo(arg1,arg2){console.log(Map[arg1]);
```

> I want to pass arg1 as key not value of agr1.

Is their a way around

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `pass as key`? You mean by reference and not by value? So you would have to object itself and not just the value?

Comment: No! I want to pass variable name!!

Comment: As string? And then...?

Comment: Okey!! I got it, I'm coding this question. I can just store the variablee name as string in another variable

Comment: Well yes, there is also a little something that could help you...`var foo = "bar"; console.log(window["foo"])` returns `"bar"`

Comment: I just want to point out that what you think is gonna reduce your code is gonna end up making your program an unmaintainable mess which you will surely regret in the future. Less code != better code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need variable names you can try something like this:

```js
function foo(arg1, arg2, Arg3){
  var Args = Array.apply(null, arguments);debugger
  var ArgNames = (foo+"").match(/\(([.\s\S]*?)\)/)[1].replace(/[\s ]/g,"");
  ArgNames = !ArgNames ? [] : ArgNames.split(",");
  for(var i in ArgNames) console.log(ArgNames[i]+": "+Args[i]);
  console.log("Value of arguments: "+Args);
  console.log("Name Of arguments: "+ArgNames);
};
foo(100,40,"BTTOLA");
```

---

**This way works fine even the function does not have any arguments or even if is defined in a few lines.**

functions below are supported by this way:

```
function foo(a, b){...};

function foo(
   a, 
   b
 ){
   ...
};

var foo=function(a, b){...};
```

Or if `foo` is an `Arrow` function like this:

```
var foo = (a, b) => {...}
```

you can try it similar this (**which works fine for Arrow and simple functions both**):

```js
var foo = (arg1, arg2, Arg3) => {
  var ArgNames = (foo+"").match(/\(([.\s\S]*?)\)/)[1].replace(/[\s ]/g,"");
  ArgNames=ArgNames?ArgNames.split(","):[];
  console.log(ArgNames);
};
foo(100,40,"BTTOLA");
```

Comment: But, what happens with minification? :D